# How to convert a LiveData List to a LiveData PagedList in PagedListAdapter

Tags: java, android, pagedlist

I am implementing a PagedList adapter in my recyclerview based on the PagedLibrary. I found the issue of converting my LiveData list into a pagedlist. I found some online posts that they are either adding a DataSource.Factory or using the transfromation.map to convert to list. I have no idea to implement them into my adapter and make it work.

Also, is it a must to have a DataSource.Factory so that it can compute the "DIFF_CALLBACK"?

Any good reference can share?

**Update - my Pagedlist adapter**

```
public class myPagedListAdapter extends PagedListAdapter<String, myPagedListAdapter.myViewholder> {



    List<String> district;
    public myPagedListAdapter(List<String> s){
        super(DIFF_CALLBACK); //new to calculate when to load data
        this.mlist= s;
    }




    @NonNull
    @Override
    public myViewholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card,
                parent, false);
        myViewholder viewholder = new myViewholder(v);
        return viewholder;

    }


    public class myViewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView districtText;
        public myViewholder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Text);
        }

    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull myViewholder holder, int position) {
        holder.Text.setText(mlist.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mlist.size();
    }

    public void setData(List<String> list){
        this.mlist= list;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    private static DiffUtil.ItemCallback<String> DIFF_CALLBACK =
            new DiffUtil.ItemCallback<String>() {

                @Override
                    public boolean areItemsTheSame(String oldItem, String newItem) {
                    // The ID property identifies when items are the same.
                    return oldItem.getid() == newItem.getid();
                }

                @Override
                public boolean areContentsTheSame(String oldItem, String newItem) {
                    // Don't use the "==" operator here. Either implement and use .equals(),
                    // or write custom data comparison logic here.
                    return oldItem.equals(newItem);
                }
            };
}
```

Comment: Provide some code snippets for your implementation. Explain are you using DataSource.Factory from Room or a Custom one?

Comment: @abstractArrow Thanks for reply. I started my adapter from a recyclerview adapter. I am fetching my data from sharedpreference as testing. Later on, i will be using ROOM or cache. After following the steps in android website, i found that i need to convert my list to a pagedlist and i got stuck.

Comment: Your Welcome Howard, I have an MVVM implementation but it's based on Kotlin. It takes me a while to convert it to Java. Let me know I sharing this code in either Java or Kotlin helps you.